# How to read user input until EOF?

Tags: python, string, input, eof

My current code reads user input until line-break.
But I am trying to change that to a format, where the user can write input until strg+d to end his input.

I currently do it like this:

```
input = raw_input ("Input: ")
```

But how can I change that to an EOF-Ready version?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use [`file.read`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.read):

```
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
```

According to the documentation:

> `file.read([size])`
>
> Read at most size bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF
>   before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or
>   omitted, read all data until EOF is reached.

```
>>> import sys
>>> isinstance(sys.stdin, file)
True
```

BTW, dont' use `input` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 87):

In Python 3 you can [iterate over the lines](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) of [standard input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin), the loop will stop when EOF is reached:

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
  print(line, end='')
```

`line` includes the trailing `\n` character

Run this example online: https://ideone.com/rUXCIe

---

This might be what most people are looking for, however if you want to just read the whole input until EOF into a single variable (like OP), then you might want to look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21235913/1916449).

Answer (score 26):

You could also do the following:

```
acc = []
out = ''
while True:
    try:
        acc.append(raw_input('> ')) # Or whatever prompt you prefer to use.
    except EOFError:
        out = '\n'.join(acc)
        break
```

Comment: This might be handier than sys.stdin.read when `readline` is imported.

Answer (score 10):

With `sys.stdin.readline()` you could write like this:

```
import sys

while True:
    input_ = sys.stdin.readline()
    if input_ == '':
        break
    print type(input_)
    sys.stdout.write(input_)
```

Remember, whatever your input is, it is a string.

For `raw_input` or `input` version, write like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        input_ = input("Enter:\t")
        #or
        _input = raw_input("Enter:\t")
    except EOFError:
        break
    print type(input_)
    print type(_input)
    print input_
    print _input
```