# How to read user input until EOF in python?

Tags: python, eof

I came across this problem in UVa OJ. [272-Text Quotes](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=208)

Well, the problem is quite trivial. But the thing is I am not able to read the input. The input is provided in the form of text lines and end of input is indicated by EOF.
In C/C++ this can be done by running a while loop:

```
while( scanf("%s",&s)!=EOF ) { //do something }
```

How can this be done in python .?

I have searched the web but I did not find any satisfactory answer.

Note that the input must be read from the console and not from a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read user input until EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235855/how-to-read-user-input-until-eof)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sys` module:

```
import sys

complete_input = sys.stdin.read()
```

[sys.stdin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) is a file like object that you can treat like a [Python File object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object).

From the documentation:

> Help on built-in function read:
>
> read(size=-1, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
> Read at most n characters from stream.
>
> ```
> Read from underlying buffer until we have n characters or we hit EOF.
> If n is negative or omitted, read until EOF.
> ```

Comment: What signals the input to terminate in this case then? Can u please see the input format given the problem [ link provided in the question]. I am not sure whether this works for this or not.  Thanks

Comment: @rohan the EOF character, the same as C/C++

Answer (score 6):

You can read input from console till the end of file using `sys` and `os` module in python. I have used these methods in online judges like SPOJ several times.

**First method (recommened):**

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
    if line == '': # If empty string is read then stop the loop
        break
    process(line) # perform some operation(s) on given string
```

Note that there will be an end-line character `\n` at the end of every line you read. If you want to avoid printing 2 end-line characters while printing `line` use `print(line, end='')`.

**Second method:**

```
import os
# here 0 and 10**6 represents starting point and end point in bytes.
lines = os.read(0, 10**6).strip().splitlines() 
for x in lines:
    line = x.decode('utf-8') # convert bytes-like object to string
    print(line)
```

This method does not work on all online judges but it is the fastest way to read input from a file or console.

**Third method:**

```
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == '':
        break
    process(line)
```

replace `input()` with `raw_input()` if you're *still* using python 2.

Comment: A comparison between methods 1 and 2 in terms of their time taken to read the input will make things clear. ..?

Answer (score 5):

For HackerRank and HackerEarth platform below implementation is preferred:

```
while True:
try :
    line = input()
    ...
except EOFError:
    break;
```

Answer (score 3):

This how you can do it :

```
while True:
   try :
      line = input()
      ...
   except EOFError:
      pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read one character on the keyboard at a time, you can see an implementation of `getch` in Python: [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/1513933)

Comment: Thanks for this idea. This can be done certainly but this will cause the problem solution to include a whole module just to read input. which will not be very efficient bearing in mind that this is a constrained problem.