# Is there a way to get inputs as a list.?

Tags: python

I looked it up and only found split() but couldnt use it, it gave an error. Is there a way to get all inputs at once.

```
total = 0
a = int(input("Enter your age"))
b = int(input("Enter your age"))
c = int(input("Enter your age"))
d = int(input("Enter your age"))
e = int(input("Enter your age"))

Age_List = [a, b, c, d, e]

for x in Age_List:
    if x > 3:
        total += 100
    else:
        continue
print(total)
```

Comment: *"found split() but couldnt use it, it gave an error"* - What was the error?

Comment: EOF but i might have used it wrong. Used it for the first time

Comment: Show us the code you tried for split, and the full error traceback message.

Comment: "*EOF*" is not an error; can you share the code that didn't work as a [mre]?

Comment: EOF means there weren't any values anymore. You can't read 5 values if you are given only less than 5 values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read user input until EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235855/how-to-read-user-input-until-eof)

Answer (score 0):

**To get list of 5 elements from input**

```
x = [int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: This worked thanks

Comment: @Yigit148 there's no reason why *this would work but your code wouldn't* unless the inputs were different

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my code works but i wanted a way to get multiple inputs with one line of code and didnt know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take inputs inside loop.

```
total = 0
for i in range(5):
    age = int(input())
    if age > 3:
        total += 100
    else:
        continue
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you so much